# Why is the turtle not turning?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My turtle won't move with my key press. When you remove the self.forward part, it turns just fine, but when it moves it doesn't work. How can I make it so that turtle turns while it is moving. Also, what was it that didn't work in my code before. Also, the image labeled backround isn't loading. How do I fix that? Thanks. Code:

```
import turtle
import turtle as trtl

color = input("Please select color of turtle: ")


# classes
class enemy(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape='square')
        self.color('white')
        self.turtlesize(2)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, 240)


class player(turtle.Turtle):

    def __init__(self, x=True):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape='turtle')
        self.x = x
        self.color(color)
        self.turtlesize(2)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(4.440892098500626e-14, -180.0)
        self.setheading(90)
        self.showturtle()
        while self.x:
            self.forward(10)
            self.speed('slowest')

    def turning_left(self):
        self.x = False
        self.left(30)
        self.x = True

    def turning_right(self):
        self.x = False
        self.right(30)
        self.x = True


enemy1 = enemy()
shooter = player()

# controls


wn = trtl.Screen()

wn.onkeypress(shooter.turning_right, 'Right')
wn.onkeypress(shooter.turning_left, 'Left')
wn.onkeypress(shooter.turning_right, 'd')
wn.onkeypress(shooter.turning_left, 'a')

wn.listen()
wn.bgpic('backround.gif')
turtle.done()
```

Comment: `__init__()` only gets called once when you initiate player

Comment: What you want is a game loop http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simplification of your code that's further modified such that the turtle constantly moves forward but you can cause it to turn via the keyboard:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

class player(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='turtle')
        self.hideturtle()
        self.turtlesize(2)
        self.setheading(90)
        self.penup()
        self.backward(180.0)
        self.showturtle()

        self.move()

    def move(self):
        self.forward(1)
        screen.ontimer(self.move)

    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(15)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(15)

shooter = player()

screen.onkeypress(shooter.turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(shooter.turn_left, 'Left')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```